# Query that filters out Elastic Search result to avoid duplicate rid's in the data

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

=> Let's say there is an Index `I1` which is defined on a Type/Mapping `M1`.

=> There are documents stored from `d1.... dn` of type/Mapping `M1` which has a `id` attribute (unique) and `rid` (rootid) attribute which is not unique but is common for some sets of id's.

=> Every search using index `I1` yeilds documents `dx...dy`.

**Problem:** Need to figure out a way to query the index `I1` which yields document `dm.... dn` such that `rid` (rootid) is unique. Simply put, filter out duplicate rids.

**Work Around:** Do a `O(n)` way of filtering them out in the search result using a proxy layer.

**EFFICIENT SOLUTION:** Model the elastic data using Parent-Child Relationship in mappings (this solution needs time and a rehaul of the existing data as well)

Is there a way to have an Elastic Search DSL query in such a way that we can do this directly in the indexer itself?

Answer (score 0):

There are three approaches to this problem

- Using parent-child modelling which needs considerable change in the
  existing data.
- [Using collapse feature Elastic search(single field
  collapse is supported till 5.6, multi-field collapse from 6.x
  onwards). (this approach doesnt yeild exact count)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-collapse.html)
- Use a flag and maintain the same as true for only one of the
  rid(rootid) and false for remaining, and have a condition on the flag
  in the search query.(simple and solves all the cases)